# Spring Security -- Retrieving the Username of the user currently trying to log in

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I need to implement a `PasswordEncoder` that generates salted passwords. The salts are user-specific (UUIDs) and stored in the corresponding `User` objects.

As such, I need access to either the `User` directly or the `UserDetails` object that holds a reference. Very easy to retrieve IF I had the name of the user trying to log in.

And therein lies the issue. I cannot seem to get a hold of it.

As far as the `SecurityContext` is concerned, we are still dealing with an `anonymousUser`.

I know there should be a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` lying around, somewhere, but I cannot inject that as it's not a bean. And to define a wrapper bean holding it, I would need to figure out where to find it in the first place.

**How do I get the name of the user trying to log in?**

Would greatly appreciate the help. :)

(Sidenote: Please don't recommend me to "not do that" or to migrate the passwords and start using a `BCryptPasswordEncoder` or something along these lines. It's something we would very much *like* to do at some point in the future but for the time being are not allowed to.)

Comment: Can't you look at the current incoming http request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do this with a `PasswordEncoder` alone as the abstraction assumes that you can encode the password using only the plain text password (or compare using the hashed password). However, if you use a custom `AuthenticationProvider` (which is what calls the `PasswordEncoder`), you will have access to the incoming `Authentication` object including the username. More info [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider).

Answer (score 1):

The call to `PasswordEncoder.matches(...)` is made by the `additionalAuthenticationChecks(...)` method of `DaoAuthenticationProvider`, which does have access to the username value (`principal`).

If you need access to that, you need to subclass `DaoAuthenticationProvider` and override (replace) the method, and make sure Spring uses your subclass when configuring.

Comment: Why override the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` and not the `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider`? It seems like the easier thing to do.

Comment: @User1291 [`DaoAuthenticationProvider`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.html) extends `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider`

Comment: yes, but it also uses the `PasswordEncoder` all over the place, forcing me to override basically everything. Don't see the point in that.

Comment: @User1291 The point is that you only need to override one method, so much less code to write.